# How to create persistent queries in JCEF

Tags: ipc, chromium-embedded

#### About my app

I have a hybrid application in which I use *JCEF* (java chromium embedded framework).

#### What I am trying to achieve

**Set up a simple subscription system using JCEF's IPC capabilities. One of which is   *message routing*.**  
Inside the relevant class (*CefMessageRouter.java*). It talks about some use cases:

```
// Some possible usage patterns include:
//
// 1.One-time Request. ...
// 2.Broadcast. ...
// 3.Subscription. Use a persistent query to register as a JavaScript subscription
//    receiver. The Handler initiates the subscription feed on the first request
//    and delivers responses to all registered subscribers as they become
//    available. The Handler cancels the subscription feed when there are no
//    longer any registered JavaScript receivers.
```

Third option is what I want. As you can see it requires a persistent query.

#### What I tried

Inside my main class:

```
CefMessageRouter msgRouter = CefMessageRouter.create(new CefMessageRouterConfig("cefQuery", "cefQueryCancel"));
msgRouter.addHandler(new MessageRouterHandler(), isTransparent);
        
client_ = cefApp_.createClient();
client_.addMessageRouter(msgRouter);
```

*MessageRouteHandler.java*

```
//imports...    
public class MessageRouterhandler implements CefMessageRouterHandler{

    @Override
    public void setNativeRef(String identifer, long nativeRef) {}

    @Override
    public long getNativeRef(String identifer) { return 0;}

    @Override
    public boolean onQuery(CefBrowser browser, CefFrame frame, long queryId, String request, boolean persistent,
            CefQueryCallback callback) {
        
        callback.success("{\"by\": \"cat\", \"message\": \"I hate you\"}");
        callback.success("{\"by\": \"dog\", \"message\": \"I love you\"}");
        
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onQueryCanceled(CefBrowser browser, CefFrame frame, long queryId) {}
}
```

*from javascript*

```
window.cefQuery({
            request: 'get-data',
            persistent: true,
            onSuccess: function(response) {
                console.log(response)
            },
            onFailure: function(error_code, error_message) {
                console.log(error_code+":"+error_message);
            }
        })
```

#### Output

With this setup what I except to get inside console:

```
{"by": "cat", "message": "I hate you"}
{"by": "dog", "message": "I love you"}
```

What I actually get:

```
{"by": "cat", "message": "I hate you"}
```

I don't understand why since documentation says:

```
// If the query is persistent then the callbacks will remain registered until one of the
// following conditions are met:
//
// A. The query is canceled in JavaScript using the |window.cefQueryCancel|
//    function.
// B. The query is canceled in C++ code using the Callback::Failure function.
// C. The context associated with the query is released due to browser
//    destruction, navigation or renderer process termination.
```

In my case it seems like no condition is met. But callback doesn't remain registered.

#### Questions

Is this a bug or am I missing something? If it is a bug. Is there any other options I can explore?

#### Edit:

Just found out there are people like me having the same problem with persistent queries. There is a issue for this problem: https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef/issues/186

Answer (score 1):

One query can only have one response. Your second success() call will thus be ignored.

Comment: So, how can I send data multiple times to the render process with one query?

Comment: You could try to redirect to a special yourprogram:// url and intercept that from the jcef side. Then use the execute javascript functionality to answer from the jcef side.